# Append an option in select after calling ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to append an option for each row in the ajax return to my select,

right now it's displaying the option as:

```
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object]
```

for each option, not the data it returns in my Json.

hitting the url directly will display the list correctly.

here is my return Json:

```
{
"id": 6658,
"unitId": 3239,
}
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
 $('#siteGroupId').on('change', function (e) {
    var siteGroupId = $(this).val();
    if(siteGroupId == '') {
        alert("Location doesn't have a department");
        $('#unitDeptNbr').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#unitDeptNbr').prop('disabled', false);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  'getUnitGroup.ajx?siteGroupId=' + siteGroupId,
            success: function (json) {
                //jQuery('#unitDeptNbr').html('');
                jQuery.each(json, function(key, value) {
                    jQuery('#unitDeptNbr')
                        .append(jQuery('<option>')
                            .text(value)
                            .attr('value', key));
                });

            }, error: function () {
                $('#unitDeptNbr').prop('disabled', true);
                alert('Error occur ...!')
            }
        });
    }
```

my jsp:

```
       <select path="deptNbr" id="unitDeptNbr" disabled="">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: The part of your code which generates the `option` elements works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/phu94j1d/. Double check the JSON that's being returned is exactly what you believe it to be.

Comment: And what is returned when you `console.log(key + value);` in each on success?? returned a correct values?? or say what your code do and what you expect your code to do .. and any errors on console??

Comment: the console is printing the right JSON data

Comment: it's working for me now, I needed to change the" .text(value)" to " text(value.id)